# Why are generic arguments used instead of direct interface/abstract classes names?

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract

Let's say you've got a method which takes a class which is an instance of the interface `Parent` as the first and only parameter, just like this one:

```
public void doSomething(Parent parent) {}
```

Let's also say we've got a class `Child` which `implements` the interface `Parent`.

Why are many people using this method head:

```
public <T extends Parent> doSomething(T parent) {}
```

instead of this one:

```
public void doSomething(Parent parent) {}
```

Are there any advantages? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, I googled a bit around for this question, but didn't find something similar so I thought it would be worth asking here.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help!
//edit: flagged it myself as a duplicate, as it's solved.